# How to return a value when animation is over

Tags: java, javafx

What I'm trying to achieve is to return an integer value after an animation is over.

I have this code:

```
public void spin(){
    symbol = queue.poll();
    this.setImage(symbol);
    queue.add(symbol);
}

private int randomize(int min, int max){
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Random rand = new Random(seed);
    return  rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
}

public int getKey() {
    return this.queue.peek().getKey();
}

public int play() {
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), e -> spin());
    Timeline tl = new Timeline(kf);
    tl.setCycleCount(randomize(10,50));
    tl.play();
    tl.setOnFinished(e -> { // Incompatible types: unexpected return value
        return this.queue.peek().getKey(); // Incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    });
    return e;
}
```

I am working on a Slot Machine game to enhance my java programming skills. I have a Symbol class which have two properties (an ImageView for the symbol, and an integer key). Then I have a Reel class which contains a queue of symbol objects. (The code above is from my Reel class). A click would call the play method which in turn fires an animation that call the spin() method a generated number of times. The spin method basically poll symbol from the queue then add it to the queue again. (This keeps rotating which symbol is at the head of the queue). then simply have the getKey() method which return an integer value (the key property of the symbol object that is currently the head of the queue). I would like to be able to return this latter from the play() method right when the animation is finished. But I have syntax errors around the setOnFinished: "Incompatible types: unexpected return value". Could someone help me understand what is wrong with my code and how I should approach this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `setOnFinished` expects an `EventHandler`: the method in `EventHandler` is `void`, so it doesn't return a value. Hence "Unexpected return value". Can you explain what you are trying to do? When the animation finishes you are trying to return some value: where are you expecting this value to be received?

Comment: `setOnFinished` is designed to take an `EventHandler` which simply executes when it is called. A return here does not seem logical. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to return an `int` of some value?

Comment: @James_D Whoa are comments are so similar lol

Comment: Thank you @James_D for the explanations. I have improved my question above. I hope I was clear enough. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you @Michael for the explanations. I have improved my question above. I hope I was clear enough. Let me know.

Comment: @James_D I'm expecting my value to be received in my main class when I fire my animation. Ex: Reel myReel = new Reel(); int x = myReel.play(); -- x will receive an integer value once the animation is finished.

Answer (score 0):

This simply isn't the way the animation API is designed: it follows an event-driven model. The `Timeline.play()` method exits immediately (i.e. before the animation is finished), and so execution reaches the end of your method long before the animation completes. There is obviously no value available from the `onFinished` handler at this point.

Instead, you should think of the `onFinished` handler as providing the code to execute when the animation completes. So you should do something like:

```
public void play() {
    KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(20), e -> spin());
    Timeline tl = new Timeline(kf);
    tl.setCycleCount(randomize(10,50));
    tl.play();
    tl.setOnFinished(e -> { 
        int x = this.queue.peek().getKey(); 
        // do whatever you need to do with x here....
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @James_D this makes sens. Initially, I had the same idea you suggested above, except, x is not accessible outside the lambda scope, so I can't really return the value of x. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Solve what? Just do whatever you need to do with that value in the lambda expression block.